# Iterating through firebase collection of varying lengths

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display the data in the sub-collection called 'user_orders' in a **list view**, each document(Highlighted in Green) contains the items the user bought in a list called 'cart'. **The aim is to show this cart data in a list** but the problem is the length of the cart varies/changes according to what the user ordered which causes a problem(Range error) when trying to iterate through multiple user_orders documents

[image]

I've been trying to use a StreamBuilder but [index] in this case only returns the first value. I'm really new to flutter and would appreciate the help.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('orders')
            .doc(user.user.uid)
            .collection('user_orders')
            .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, orderSnapshot) {
        return orderSnapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: orderSnapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot orderData = orderSnapshot.data.documents[index];
                      return ListTile(
                          title: Text(orderData.get('cart')[index]['title']),
                      );
                  },
              ) : LoadingPage();
           },
       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently only displaying one of the of values of the `cart` per document. You should do something like this:

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('orders')
          .doc("uid")
          .collection('user_orders')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, orderSnapshot) {
        if (orderSnapshot.hasData) {
          final carts = orderSnapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.get("cart"));
          final cartValues =
              carts.entries.expand((element) => element).toList();

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cartValues.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final title = cartValues[index]["title"];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(title),
              );
            },
          );
        }
        return LoadingPage();
      },
    );
```

Please note I have not tried running this piece of code, it may contain errors, but it's enough to guide you, I believe.

Comment: This solution worked with minor tweaking, I had to remove the (.value) after element Final soln>> final cartValues =
              carts.entries.expand((element) => element).toList()

Comment: @TMoreMaker Glad it ahs worked for you, updated the answer to reflect your improvement for future reference.